# Arduino-Controlled LED Matrix issues

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, power, rgb-led, windows

I am making a 20 x 15 LED matrix, and am having some super annoying problems. I was hoping you all could help me find some answers.

It is very important to note that I am following [BitLuni's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fz2QAV9z_o8) on this, following it using almost the same parts, and most definitely the same code (I put it below)

To start, this are the main things I am making it with:

6 sets of [RGB LED Pixel Lights](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076VBSB3B)

1 [Knock-off Arduino NANO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FSDVZ98)

1 [5v 20A Power Supply](https://www.ebay.com/itm/AC-110V-to-DC-5V-12V-24V-36V-48V-Transformer-Switch-Power-Supply-For-LED-Strip/172430906024?_trkparms=aid%3D1110001%26algo%3DSPLICE.SIM%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20131231084308%26meid%3Dc81b057721f042b4b03ca582d744c6fa%26pid%3D100010%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D12%26mehot%3Dpp%26sd%3D392379761659%26itm%3D172430906024%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2047675&_trksid=p2047675.c100010.m2109)

My first problem arose when I received the Arduino Nano. I was able to see it, but not able to write to it. I was eventually able to make it work by using the old boot loader. Let me make it clear, I fixed that problem. But then I short circuited it and bought another one. And now I am faced with the same problem. I have tried using the [company's own drivers](https://wiki.keyestudio.com/Ks0173_keyestudio_Nano_ch340#Step2.7C_Installing_the_Driver) on the darn thing, same issue. 
I was going to put the error here, but when I tried to flash, my computer (Windows) got the blue screen of death. I tried opening the app just now, instant death. So I suppose I'll just reinstall it, just saying, something is MESSED UP with it.

Pretty much, I get the error "the selected serial port does not exist or your board is not connected. "I know for a fact that the COM Port is correct, but it just doesn't seem to like what I am doing.

But I still have another problem. While I had the arduino that I got to work, when I transitioned from using the 5v power supply on it to using the power supply I bought, the lights go nuts. They change to seemingly random colors super fast. But as soon as I change it back to the arduino's power, it was fine. I have tested, and the power output is PRECISELY THE SAME. The arduino just sends out the data for the lights to interpret. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

So if you have anything to suggest for either of the problems, I would appreciate it.

Also, here is my code for the lights (sorry this post is really chopped up) It is based on Adafruit_NeoMatrix example

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoMatrix.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifndef PSTR
 #define PSTR // Make Arduino Due happy
#endif

#define PIN 6

// MATRIX DECLARATION:
// Parameter 1 = width of NeoPixel matrix
// Parameter 2 = height of matrix
// Parameter 3 = pin number (most are valid)
// Parameter 4 = matrix layout flags, add together as needed:
//   NEO_MATRIX_TOP, NEO_MATRIX_BOTTOM, NEO_MATRIX_LEFT, NEO_MATRIX_RIGHT:
//     Position of the FIRST LED in the matrix; pick two, e.g.
//     NEO_MATRIX_TOP + NEO_MATRIX_LEFT for the top-left corner.
//   NEO_MATRIX_ROWS, NEO_MATRIX_COLUMNS: LEDs are arranged in horizontal
//     rows or in vertical columns, respectively; pick one or the other.
//   NEO_MATRIX_PROGRESSIVE, NEO_MATRIX_ZIGZAG: all rows/columns proceed
//     in the same order, or alternate lines reverse direction; pick one.
//   See example below for these values in action.
// Parameter 5 = pixel type flags, add together as needed:
//   NEO_KHZ800  800 KHz bitstream (most NeoPixel products w/WS2812 LEDs)
//   NEO_KHZ400  400 KHz (classic 'v1' (not v2) FLORA pixels, WS2811 drivers)
//   NEO_GRB     Pixels are wired for GRB bitstream (most NeoPixel products)
//   NEO_RGB     Pixels are wired for RGB bitstream (v1 FLORA pixels, not v2)


// Example for NeoPixel Shield.  In this application we'd like to use it
// as a 5x8 tall matrix, with the USB port positioned at the top of the
// Arduino.  When held that way, the first pixel is at the top right, and
// lines are arranged in columns, progressive order.  The shield uses
// 800 KHz (v2) pixels that expect GRB color data.
Adafruit_NeoMatrix matrix = Adafruit_NeoMatrix(20, 15, PIN,
  NEO_MATRIX_TOP     + NEO_MATRIX_LEFT +
  NEO_MATRIX_ROWS + NEO_MATRIX_ZIGZAG,
  NEO_GRB            + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  matrix.begin();
  matrix.setTextWrap(false);
  matrix.setBrightness(255);
}

int x    = matrix.width();
int pass = 0;

void loop() {
  static int i = 0;
  i++;
  //matrix.fillScreen(0);
  for(int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
      if(y & 1)
        matrix.setPixelColor(19 - x + y * 20, matrix.gamma32(matrix.ColorHSV((x + y) * 256 * 8 + i * 128 * 2)));
      else
        matrix.setPixelColor(x + y * 20, matrix.gamma32(matrix.ColorHSV((x + y) * 256 * 8+ i * 128 * 2)));

  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color(0, 0, 0));
  matrix.setCursor(-((millis() / 30) & 127) + 20, 4);
  matrix.print(F(""));
  matrix.show();
}
```

Thanks all!

-Micah

Comment: Do you connect the GND of the second power supply to the GND of the arduino? The LEDs and the arduino need a common voltage reference on the control pin.

Comment: If you disconnect and connect the nano the COM port might change. But in the IDE the it does not change automatically. But this is just a very rough guess. I don't expect this to be correct.

Comment: @jsotola Sorry for not being specific enough and cluttering my post, I'll fix that. I was mostly asking in the post if I was missing anything or doing something wrong with the panel because I was having issues.

Comment: Thank you so much @PeterPaulKiefer! That actually fixed my light problem! I still need to fix the arduino problems but that you so much!

Comment: Update: I ended up just returning the arduino and purchasing another one.